# Do certain brands have sponsorship agreeements in place on Teen Mom 2?

Tags: teen-mom

During tonight's *Teen Mom 2* episode, I saw three people (including Kailyn and Leah) wearing Under Armour apparel. Typically, *Teen Mom* and other shows blur out brand names so that they don't give away free advertising. But in this case, do certain brands have sponsorship agreeements in place?

Comment: Sounds like typical product placement.

Comment: Are questions about advertising not directly about movies or tv on topic? I think not.